# Sum of coefficients in the expansion of $(2x+3y-2z)^n$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Sum of coefficients in the expansion of $(2x+3y-2z)^n$ is $2187$ then the greatest coefficient in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$.

I put $x=y=z=1$ in the expansion. So, sum of coefficients became equal to $(2+3-2)^n=3^n$.
So, $3^n=2187\implies n=7$
Hence, greatest coefficient in expansion of $(1+x)^7$ is, ${}^7C_3={}^7C_4=35$

But I am not satisfied with this method. Is there another method to solve this without substituting some value of $x, y, z$?

Comment: It looks a smart method to me

Comment: This is really the easiest way to find the sum of the coefficients of a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $(2x + 3y - 2z)^n$ will have a separate term for each solution to the following equation:

- $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = n.$
- $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

That is, by Stars and Bars theory, the polynomial will have $\displaystyle \binom{n+2}{2}~$ terms, which represents $a_1$ ranging from $0$ through $n$, and $a_2$ ranging from $0$ through $(n - a_1).$

For any corresponding solution represented by $~(a_1,a_2,a_3),~$ the corresponding term in the polynomial that represents

$$\text{coefficient} ~\times (2x)^{a_1} \times (3y)^{a_2} \times (-2z)^{a_3}$$

can actually be re-expressed as

$$\text{coefficient} ~\times \left[2^{a_1}3^{a_2}(-2)^{a^3}\right] \times x^{a_1} \times y^{a_2} \times z^{a_3} \tag1 $$

where

$$\text{(multinomial) coefficient} ~=~ \frac{n!}{a_1! \times a_2! \times a_3!}, \tag2 $$

The easiest way to compute the **sum** of the $~\displaystyle \binom{n+2}{2}~$ numbers that are  **collectively** represented by (1) and (2) above is to set $(x,y,z) = (1,1,1),$ which forces each corresponding expression of $~\displaystyle x^{a_1} \times y^{a_2} \times z^{a_3}~$ to equal **one**.

Then, by the **trinomial** expansion of an expression of the form $(r + s + t)^n$, you have that
the sum of the $~\displaystyle \binom{n+2}{2}~$ numbers that are  collectively represented by (1) and (2) above is $(2 + 3 - 2)^n.$

Comment: That's the same way as I mentioned in the question. Is there an alternative method?

Comment: @SouparnaPal I agree that it is the same way that you mentioned.  The best that I could do is to provide an analytical demonstration that that is the only **elegant** method possible (or at least that I am aware of).  In the same way, imagine that you wanted to compute $$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}.$$  To the best of my knowledge, the only elegant approach is to notice that the expression corresponds to the binomial expansion of $(1 + 1)^n.$

Comment: The numerator of $(2)$ should be $n!,$ not $3!.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews +1 : nice catch, thanks.  Answer edited.